# Html.ActionLink Including extra parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Using the following code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("News", "Index", new { controller = "News", area = "" }, new { @class = "News" })
```

I'm getting an error so that when I'm on a particular news article, the link is generating as:

http://mywebsite/News/2011/12/2/my_slug

where the parameters match the page that I'm currently on.  The also happens on other controllers matching the same url schema (imagine I have another controller called Presentations that matches the url scheme of News entirely).  From the presentations pages, a link to news would include the presentations parameters which aren't valid input for the news controller.  Make sense?

I have my routes defined as:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "News-Archive", // Route name
            "News/Archive", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "News", action = "Archive" }, // Parameter defaults
            new[] { "mywebsite.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "News-Stub", // Route name
            "News/{year}/{month}/{date}/{slug}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "News", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
            new[] { "mywebsite.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "News-ByDay", // Route name
            "News/{year}/{month}/{day}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "News", action = "Archive" }, // Parameter defaults
            new[] { "mywebsite.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "News-ByMonth", // Route name
          "News/{year}/{month}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "News", action = "Archive" }, // Parameter defaults
          new[] { "mywebsite.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "News-ByYear", // Route name
          "News/{year}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "News", action = "Archive" }, // Parameter defaults
          new[] { "mywebsite.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "News-Default", // Route name
          "News", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "News", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
          new[] { "mywebsite.Controllers" }
        );
```

Can someone please explain if the problem lies in my use of Html.ActionLink or my route definitions?

EDIT:

Changing the Actionlink to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("News", "Index", new { controller = "News", area = "", year = string.Empty, month = string.Empty, day = string.Empty, slug = string.Empty}, null)
```

results in this when called from a presentation page (those values are for the presentation, not a valid news item):

http://mywebsite/News?year=2011&month=12&slug=seo_overview

Not sure why that's causing the rewriting to change.

Answer (score 0):

The action link assumes the current slug since no slug was provided:

Use

```
 ActionLink("News", "Index", new { controller = "News", area = "", slug="newslug"}, new { @class = "News" })
```

or

```
 ActionLink("News", "Index", new { controller = "News", area = "", slug = null}, new { @class = "News" })
```

There is a chance that setting the slug = null would also re-use the current slug, in that case set the slug = Empty String.

Comment: slug = null results in an error saying cannot assign null to anonymous type property.  Setting it to empty also seems to be ignored.

Comment: Use the first example, set the slug to where ever you want the slug to link to. What happens is the slug is being pulled from the current route data. If you don't over-ride the value of the current page, the helper thinks that it should use the existing route data's slug since none was specified in your ActionLink.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify.  I want /News to go to the most recent article, /News/year/month/date to go to archives for that year/month/date (or leave off date and optionally month to get filtered archives).  If you have /year/month/date/slug then I want to display that particular article.  I'm trying to link back to the main /News page, but it is picking up all of these ambient values that I want it to ignore.  If I set slug = string.empty it gets ignored (see my edit above).

Comment: The one thing you have to learn is that the build in link/url generators are going to always inherit the current pages RouteValues. That means when you are viewing a page that matched the News-Stub route, the values for Year, Month, Date and Slug are going to be there. You could use Url.Action and specify a route name and build your own link: <a href="@Url.Action("News-Default")">News</a>. You could also build your own HTML Helper that allows you to create an ActionLink by Route Name.

Comment: Thanks, I wound up using Html.RouteLink with named routes to get it working.